# How Can I Tell if a WebsphereMQ Message Was Delivered to a Remote Queue?

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm sending a message to a remote (offsite) MQ server.  The recipient says they don't get the message I send, but it looks like things are good on my side.  For example, if I stop the XMITQ, the messages I send pile up there until I restart it.
If there was a network problem (for example, if someone changed a firewall/router setting on my end) what would happen to the message I send?  I would think it would end up in the dead-letter queue, but there's nothing there.  It doesn't seem to make sense that an MQ message would just disappear.

Comment: Is it a persistent message?

Comment: Yes, it's persistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could enable COD reports to prove that the receiving application actually consumed the message. Most problems of this sort are an issue with the consuming application having an error part way through processing the message and throwing it away.

Comment: You might be able to select the tick next to this answer and accept the answer though?